# 1 User Profile Sync Service with 2 domains

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, profile-sync

Here is the scenario:

I have 2 domains. Domain A is corporate, Domain B is local to our site.

Each domain has its own SharePoint that uses its respective AD and User Profile Syncs wonderfully.

The powers that be are forging ahead with a "single logon" project where users use the Domain A login ID and can still use both Sharepoints without issue or barrriers.

Accessing Domain B sites as a Domain A user is fine, it resolves users & AD groups in Domain A fine. However... I cannot seem to configure a User Profile Sync Connection in Domain B to sync users from Domain A.

We have a 1 way trust in  place.

I'm sure I need to do this as some workflows encounter issues depending on which domain user triggered it. Domain A users are also getting restricted search results on Domain B crawled file shares (none!)

Hope this made sense!

Comment: My hunch is that I need to add the Domain B sync service account as a delegate to Domain A?

Comment: Why not set up a 2-way trust between the domains? Check this [link](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-add-trust-domains-in-a-sharepoint-farm/).

Comment: Yep, that would be the simple option but it's a no go unfortunately.

Comment: I see. As far as I was aware, if SharePoint doesn't trust a domain, it will not users from that domain access it. I have just found [this short bit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602068.aspx#forests) that states that there is another option besides 2-way trust. I don't know the details, but it may help.